# How to get the data and display contents from a url javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, url

How to get a file from a url that contains a csv but my link does not contain the filename.

example: https:/api/download

This link download the csv file automatically and saves it.

How can I get the contents csv using the url but the csv automatically downloads and display the data in html code below doesnt work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCSV(func) {
    var file = "https:/api/download";
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var allText;

    rawFile.open("GET", 'API.csv', false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                allText = rawFile.responseText;
                if(func!=undefined && typeof(func) == "function"){
                    func(allText);
                 }
    };

    rawFile.send();


    }


    getCSV(function(contents){
    alert(contents);
    })
```

Comment: There isn't really a way to do this. Browsers can't natively display CSV files, so the only way to do this would be to serve the CSV as something else (eg, `text/plain` or the like) and then find a way to process it on the client side.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan how would i do that?

Comment: Hang on, I'm working on that...

Comment: @YaakovAinspan But I tried reading local csv file it works but not with this link because it downloads the csv file

Comment: I'm working on it

Comment: You can see what the data returned will look like here: https://tricksfortheweb.com/stack/csv.php

Comment: You'd have to find a way to format it properly.

Comment: Okay I'll find a way

Comment: @YaakovAinspan okay I will find a way to format the data how did you do it?

Comment: I used `file_get_contents` in PHP.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan how would you do it javascript?

Comment: I wouldn't. Try googling it

Comment: Does clicking the link return the CSV file or open a web page that automatically starts a download of the CSV file?

Comment: @traktor automatically start a download of csv

Comment: Check if you can retrieve the download page using an AJAX or fetch request. If the site prevents you then you have a problem. Otherwise see if the download page content provides the URL of the file downloaded  - possibly in a "click here if the file doesn't start to download" button code. Sounds like may need to scrape the information you need :D

Comment: @traktor53 I can retrieve the data using fetch(it downloads the csv) but I don't know how to get the data from the csv and display the content.

Comment: Is the CSV data in `contents` when the callback function is called?  If not, please update the question to explain what you expected and what you got. If the problem is how to present CSV data (that you've downloaded) as an HTML table include the code you've tried.